# I'm kinda confused, but how could serial-upvoting happen?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I was on mathexchange, then I realized that my reputation crazily went up by +180 in the blink of an eye! I realized that someone had upvoted almost all of my posts in less than 3 minutes! Then the upvoting was reversed. But how is that even possible? Is it some sort of botnet or some malfunction in the system or what? I'm quite surprised about how that all happened. Is it someone kidding with me or what?

Comment: This happened to me yesterday. Very odd. But not exactly disappointing since what's the point in a false reputation.

Answer (score 6):

There is a script that detects and reverses serial upvoting and downvoting. For what scant  details we can divulge: [[1]](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/), [[2]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124247/serial-upvoting-reversed), [[3]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134445/serial-upvoting-reversed-algorithm), [[4]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124660/serial-upvoting-reversed-issue).

Comment: Yea, I read about that just now. But how serial up-voting happens? I doubt anyone is insane enough to upvote 18 posts in a matter of 2 minutes or so. Moreover, isn't there a timer between someone's upvotes?

Comment: @some1.new4u: I've seen it happen.

Comment: @some1.new4u, my guess would be that it is possible to program a bot to do such upvoting. I don't see the appeal of such an exercise myself. However, the world is full of people with a computer and nothing better to do.

Comment: It's also possible that a new user really liked *one* of your answers, and wanted to give a big thank you. :)